# Error in removing product from cart in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I am facing an error in removing products from cart. When i add product in cart by setting the quantity and click on remove an error is displayed.

**local variable 'product' referenced before assignment**

I have product in models.py file and referring it from their by importing the models and have tried by changing the name but still it gives an error.

**views.py**

```
def update_cart(request,slug):
request.session.set_expiry(1200000)
try:
    qty=request.GET.get('qty')
    update_qty=True
except:
    qty=None
    update_qty=False
try:
    the_id=request.session['cart_id']
except:
    new_cart=Cart()
    new_cart.save()
    request.session['cart_id']=new_cart.id
    the_id=new_cart.id

cart = Cart.objects.get(id=the_id)
try:
    product=Product.objects.get(slug=slug)
except Product.DoesNotExist:
    pass
except:
    pass

cart_item,created=CartItem.objects.get_or_create(cart=cart,product=product)
if created:
    print("yeah")
    if update_qty and qty:
       if int(qty)<=0:
        cart_item.delete()
       else:
        cart_item.quantity=qty
        cart_item.save()
else:
    pass


return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("carts:cart"))
```

**models.py**

```
class CartItem(models.Model):
    cart=models.ForeignKey('Cart',on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True,blank=True)
    product=models.ForeignKey(Product,on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True,blank=True)
    accessory = models.ForeignKey(Accessories,on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True,blank=True)
    quantity=models.IntegerField(default=1)
    updated  = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,auto_now=False)
    line_total=models.DecimalField(default=10.99,max_digits=1000,decimal_places=2)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,auto_now=False)

    objects = CartManager()


    def __unicode__(self):
        try:
           return str(self.cart.id)
        except:
            return self.product.title
```

If anyone can please help it would be really appreciated?

**Note**
I have seen other link of stackoverflow but none helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your product variable is inside a `try` block, and python interpreter can't see it. You could create it outside the try block:

```
....
product = None
try:
    product=Product.objects.get(slug=slug)
```

Or move your logic to deal with the product into the try block, just after the product is assign

```
cart = Cart.objects.get(id=the_id)
try:
    product=Product.objects.get(slug=slug)
    cart_item,created=CartItem.objects.get_or_create(cart=cart,product=product)
    if created:
        print("yeah")
        if update_qty and qty:
           if int(qty)<=0:
            cart_item.delete()
           else:
            cart_item.quantity=qty
            cart_item.save()
    else:
        pass


    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("carts:cart"))
except Product.DoesNotExist:
    pass
except:
    pass
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your precious time @Stargazer Sir. The changed logic works.In first case if i add product=None out of try a None product without price is added in cart and the error is displayed None product has no price.